# What timestamp format?

Tags: time, unix-timestamp

I am getting the following format for (i guess) timestamps in some unix logfiles, but don't know what format it is and how to convert it:

The timestamp looks like this: `589702.337476`

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have any examples where you know both the timestamp value and the date/time that it's meant to correspond with? I.e. is the above value something that was recorded today? last week? 3 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

If it's in seconds, it's just under a week.

I suspect that it's the result of calling `clock_gettime()` with an argument of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`, which is defined as "monotonic time since some unspecified starting point"; it's typically the number of seconds since the system was last booted.

On my Ubuntu system, I see timestamps like that (along with real-time timestamps) in `/var/log/kern.log`.